# Sorting of file name into an array using Perl and Regex

Tags: regex, perl

```
sub open_directory {
    my $directory = shift @_;
    my @files = ();

    opendir (my $dh, $directory) or die "Couldn't open dir '$directory' : $!";
    my @all_files = readdir $dh;
    closedir $dh;

    foreach my $files(@all_files){
            while($files =~ /\.htm/){
                push(@files);
            }
    }
    return @files;
}
```

The error is at the code `push(@files);`
The error is : 
`Useless use of push with no values`

I want to process the files with the the name ending of `.htm` or `.html` in the `@files` array using the regex `/\.htm/` please help me.

Comment: There error message means that you forgot to specify _what_ to push into the array. Think about it.

Comment: Also, the `while` should really be an `if`.

Comment: i guess something like this should work? `push(@files, $files);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most simply way to solve this is by using the `grep` builtin: It selects those elements from a list where a condition is true, then returns the list of all matching elements E.g.

```
my @even = grep { $_ % 2 == 0 } 1 .. 10; # even number in the interval [1, 10].
```

In our case, we can do

```
my @files = grep { /\.htm/ } readdir $dh;
```

If you want to use `push`, then you (a) have to specify what you want to push onto the array, and (b) should only do the pushing *if* the regex matches, not *while* it matches:

```
for my $file (@all_files) {
  push @files, $file if $file =~ /\.htm/;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have solved this small problem :)
   if($files =~ /\.htm/){
    push(@files,$files);
   }

Comment: @DeepakTivari Be aware that that regex will also consider (for example) `foobar.htm.tar.gz` a valid file name. (Because the regex is not anchored to the end of the file name)

Comment: oh yes thank you for pointing that out. I am still doing beginner stuff but will remember to set the regex properly :D

Answer (score 2):

[amon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1521179/amon) has given the correct answer to your question, using `grep` to filter the file names. However, the functionality you are trying to accomplish sounds more like a [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) to me:

```
my @html_files = glob("*.html *htm");  # html files
```

You can also insert a directory:

```
my $dir = "foo";
my @html_files = glob("$dir/*.html $dir/*.htm");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to understand the below code, this will process only .htm or .html files.

```
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my @all_files = ("abc.htm", "xyz.gif", "pqr.html") ;
my @files;
foreach my $files(@all_files){
    if($files =~ /\.html?/){ # This will process only .htm or .html files
        push(@files, $files);
    }
}
print Dumper(\@files);
```

output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'abc.htm',
          'pqr.html'
        ];
```